# Bright light from window?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I'm doing an interior scene with Blender and Cycles. Scene has set following setup: Three tall windows. Each window has a portal and the light in the scene comes from a HDRI environment texture. The camera is places far in the room and pointing towards the windows.

My question is a little bit complicated, because I'm looking for an effect, that I don't know the english word for. When I look at other renderings and real photos i catalogues the sun is so bright and so much light flows through the windows, so the things in the background outside of the windows is almost unvisible.

How can I achieve that in my scene?

Comment: You are probably looking for an over-exposed or burnt exterior, this might be easier to achieve in post production by rendering indoors and outdoors as separate layers.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos OK, thanks for your comment!